# MySQL PDO Connection, how do I retrieve the inserted ID?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO connection where I am inserting a new ROW in the databse:

```
$sql = UPDATE invoices SET ..."
```

Or

```
$sql = INSERT INTO invoices ..."
```

Then:

```
$stmt = self::getPDOConnection(self::DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME)->prepare($this->sql);
$stmt->execute($this->values);
```

And I would like to get the id of the updated, inserted element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
public string PDO::lastInsertId ([ string $name = NULL ] )
```

FYI [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: Thank you, however, what if I have multiple users on the same project using different insertions, updates, I am sure that this will return the right id?

Comment: No, only the last inserted ID will be returned (this is easily tested). The only way to guarantee that you are returning the right ID to the right user is write a process or function that queries the database based on what that user just inserted into the table. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php